# Performant way of dynamic URL rewriting on tomcat

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, servlets

I am currently migrating a large website with a lot of static content (HTML files) and a bit of dynamic content.

I'm trying to create the most performant website I can by trying to make everything as static as possible and using as few servlets as I possibly can. However, since the old website supported complex URL's I will need some rewriting and would need some of it to be dynamic e.g.:
http://oldsite/url.html and http://oldsite/url would both work for the same URL...

I'm looking for performance facts e.g. with benchmark results to back this up on the impact of a statically served site.

Initially I thought I'd create a filter but that would create an overhead on every request going into the site. I thought about just using something like overriding the 404 mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324176/how-to-make-a-filter-to-detect-if-the-user-requested-a-not-found-page) and then the overhead would be relatively low (for old bookmarks/caches).

There is also the [rewrite](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/rewrite.html) option but that's both lock-in and I'm not really sure how to use it to map blank URL's to HTML files... Currently I'm guessing its the most performant way though.

Answer (score 1):

1. If the rewritings/redirections are straight forward (no regular expressions required), you could use a static [concurrent Radix Tree](https://code.google.com/p/concurrent-trees/) and initialize it with all the rewritings/redirections you want to apply. 
   In worst case, a URL that is supposed not to be renamed won't be recognized by the Radix Tree and as it is concurrent and fast, it shouldn't create a huge burden.
2. If you need regexp-like rewritings and you don't want to only depend on Apache Tomcat, you can also try [UrlRewriteFilter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) which *should* work for all the Servlet-compliant application servers.
   Even though it might seem it's quite a slow solution they [claim](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/manual/2.6/#performance) it's actually pretty fast.

Comment: Thanks, I neglected to mention that I already looked at UrlRewriteFilter though. As an answer I was looking for something more in terms of "this was benchmarked here". I'll clarify this in the question.