# Mapping an exception to 404 page while using Spring Security taglibs

Tags: java, spring, exception, spring-security, jsp-tags

When mapping an Exception to 404 page, the Spring Security tags can't find the authentication information from the security context. With a "real" 404 the authentication is found.

My web.xml:

```
<error-page>
  <exception-type>com.example.NotFoundException</exception-type>
  <location>/app/404</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
  <error-code>404</error-code>
  <location>/app/404</location>
</error-page>
```

On the JSP I have:

```
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')">
  <%-- Show navigation links --%>
</sec:authorize>
<sec:authorize access="isAnonymous()">
  <%-- Show login form --%>
</sec:authorize>
```

The `/app/404` path is mapped to a controller which just returns the view. When I browse to `/foo/some_invalid_id` the `NotFoundException` gets thrown from the controller and finally when it goes to the JSP it can't find the authentication in `SecurityContext` and renders neither of the two options. Instead, when I'm browsing to `/something_that_really_doesnt_exist` it's able to figure out whether I'm logged in or not and renders the proper HTML.

Comment: this will probably help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153438/spring-security-issue-with-404-error

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help me out.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add the following two dispatcher elements to your spring security filter-mapping:

```
<filter-mapping>
    ...
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

By default only ordinary requests go through a defined filter-mapping.

"INCLUDE" and "FORWARD" are the two other valid dispatcher element values.

Comment: Forgive my servlet/JSP ignorance, but do you mean that when, for example, a 404 occurs, the request is not typically routed thru the Spring Security filter (or any filter for that matter)? That makes perfect sense; I just want to be sure I understand what's happening here.

Comment: What you have stated is correct. For more detailed information on the subject click [here](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-03-2003/jw-0328-servlet.html?page=3).

Answer (score 0):

The most probable case is that some component in your code is calling `HttpSession.invalidate()` while exception handling. You can easily find this out by a simple debugging.

But actually it is not necessary to check for `isAnonymous()` - it is enough to check for user *not having* `ROLE_USER` authority:

- In Spring Security 2: you can use `areNotGranted` attribute of `<sec:authorize>` tag (see [Spring Security 2 documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.2.x/reference/html/ch13s09.html)
- In Spring Security 3: you can use Spring EL for evaluation of negative condition: `access="!hasRole('ROLE_USER')"`

Comment: I'm on Spring Security 3, so I could use the negation, but I guess it would then always render the login form even though the user had logged in, because the proper data isn't there.

Comment: As of the session invalidation, I found only three occasions of it and none of those got called when the exception was thrown.

Comment: If in your current setup JSP page is rendered (and not the login page), so negation should provide you the solution. If JSP page is not rendered and you're facing login page instead of it (assuming users can log into the system and at some point valid Authentication object is accessible through the SecurityContext) - check what is clearing the security context

Comment: The actual problem is that whatever the security condition is it always returns false, whether I use negation or not has nothing to do with this. There's no `SecurityContext` clearance happening except the one from `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter` which is expected.

Comment: You need to debug your setup. The scenario is pretty basic: if user is authenticated successfully, it has a SecurityContext available in the current thread (accessible with SecurityContextHolder). If after the exception there is no SecurityContext available for the current thread, something must be removing, replacing or clearing it. This is easy to find out with debugging the access to HttpSession and SecurityContextHolder. Additional area worth checking is which instance of SecurityContextHolderStrategy is used - global, TLS or inheritable TLS.