# Spring security tags do not work in error pages

Tags: jsp, spring-security

I have custom error pages for each error code I wish to handle, though I'm finding that the spring-security tags are not working when using these pages. As an example, with the below only "One" shows:

```
<%@ page session="false" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" prefix="sec" %>
<p>One</p>
<sec:authorize access="isAuthenticated()">
  <p>Two</p>
</sec:authorize>
<sec:authorize access="!isAuthenticated()">
  <p>Three</p>
</sec:authorize>
```

Specifically I am targeting the error pages provided by my `web.xml`, i.e.

```
<error-page>
  <error-code>404</error-code>
  <location>/WEB-INF/error/404-layout.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

In my controller I throw a `RuntimeException` called `ResourceNotFoundException` annotated with `@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)` for where entities were not found. This redirects to the error page correctly.

What doesn't work is exactly what's explained above, anything within a spring security tag does not render, whether it be resulting to `true` or `false`, as illustrated in my example, both tags produce no output.

Answer (score 1):

The tags will only "work" (you should probably clarify what you mean by "not working") if the page is rendered for a request which passes through the Spring Security filter chain.

The error pages you declare in your `web.xml` will be handled directly by the container and, as far as I know, there's no way to tell it to apply a filter-mapping to them.

Comment: Is that correct? Wouldn't it have already gone through the chain to get to the controller? It's the controller that will throw a `ResourceNotFoundException`. I suppose an alternate would be to setup a spring controller that the error pages map to static paths.

Comment: I'm not sure what controller you're referring to. Could you clarify in your question what type of error pages you are talking about (do you mean those defined using `error-page` in your `web.xml` or something else) and also what actually doesn't work?

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure that the servlet spec gives you any guarantees on how `error-page` pages are handled. It might even be container-specific. In any case, they are usually very simple. You might want to check by dumping the stack from one to see what it contains.

Comment: I've updated as requested, what I mean by not work is illustrated in my example, the two tags entered provide examples of trying to output both authenticated and non authenticated blocks, both produce no output.

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution to it - see answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/6199119 - it should suffice to add those additional information to filter-mapping in web.xml:

```
<filter-mapping>
    ...
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```